# uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException' - can't find variable causing issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode9

I know there are similar questions on this site that deal with this error but I cannot figure out the incongruity in my code that is causing the error.

The full error is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: 
'[<ViewController 0x7ffe26d05a50> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key description.'
```

I do not know of or see anywhere in my code that I call something "description."

Here is my code so far:

**main.m**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
  }
}
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property NSMutableArray *numbers;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *descriptionField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *costField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *numSlider;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)pressedBackward:(id)sender {
    self.nameField.text = @"backward";
    self.descriptionField.text = @"backward";
    self.costField.text = @"backward";
}

- (IBAction)pressedForward:(id)sender {
    self.nameField.text = @"forward";
    self.descriptionField.text = @"forward";
    self.costField.text = @"forward";
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{return 1;}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{return _numbers.count;}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", _numbers[row]];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        [_numbers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    }
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

I really appreciate any help in understanding why I am getting this error and cannot run my program yet.

Comment: It's so simple, open your story board file and you have draged one variable that variable connection from storyboard to variable is missed. I think  you removed variable and you are not removed from story board. thats why it's getting error

Comment: When I see `IBOutlet UITextField *descriptionField` and the error, I'd say that you named before your `UITextField` `description`, connected it in Interface Builder, but then rename it (but didn't remove the connection). I guess it's also because `description`  is already a method of Objective-C and could causes issue then.

Comment: @Larme that's exactly what I did.  How do I remove that connection now that it's renamed?

Comment: Open the storyboard, select the vc, on the inspector disconnect the old one

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is that there is a UI element miss-mapped with the *.xib* file.

Please check if the elements `image, nameField, descriptionField, costField, numSlider` are correctly linked or if there is an element in you xib/storyboard file that is linked in your ViewController but has been removed.